# Closure of an amenable subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, amenability

Let $G$ be a topological group, and let $H < G$ be a countable subgroup that is amenable as a discrete group. Is the closure of $H$ an amenable topological group?

Comment: For the fixed point definition, this is clearly true.

Comment: The perhaps surprising consequence is the following: if $H$ is countable amenable, and we want to prove that $H'$ is too, it suffices to find $G$ such that $H<G$, $H'<\overline{H}$, and $H'$ is closed in $G$.

Comment: Also for the original definition, since $C_b(\overline H)$ injects into $\ell^\infty(H)$.

Comment: @Vladimir you want locally compact $G$, all countable discrete groups embed as closed subgroups into the isometry group of the Urysohn space, which is (extremely) amenable

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @AlessandroCodenotti. This would make them amenable as topological groups, but not necessarily amenable as discrete groups.

Comment: @Vladimir amenability is inherited by closed subgroups only among locally compact groups, not in general. See Pestov's [On free actions, minimal flows, and a problem by Ellis](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1998-350-10/S0002-9947-98-02329-0/) for example, Corollary 5.6 establishes that $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Q,\leq)$ is extremely amenable, while Theorem 8.1 shows that it contains the free group on two generators as a closed subgroup

Comment: I see now. But is this free group discrete? If not then there's no contradiction, no?

Comment: Regarding my first comment in this thread, it should have also said that $H'$ is discrete in $G$.